# Nuxt 3: setting reactive data from fetch response

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

My external API endpoint returns both the json content in the body and some useful info in the headers, e.g. pagination data like `x-total-count` which I want to retrieve and hold in a reactive variable.

I successfully used `useFetch` to get the json content and I've hooked into the `onResponse` callback to obtain the header info:

```
const totalItems = ref(0)
const { data: items } = await useFetch('http://api.test/items', {
  onResponse({ request, response, options }) {
    totalItems.value = response.headers.get('x-total-count')
  }
})
```

When I navigate to the page using the router everything works as expected, i.e. the `items` array is set as expected and the `totalItems` value is set.  But when I do a hard browser refresh I momentarily see the correct `totalItems` value but then it resets back to 0.  There is definitely only one API request being made.

I've tried useAsyncData too and the closest I got was trying to manually set the ref values from the response callback...

```
await useAsyncData( async () => {
  $fetch.raw('http://api.test/items',{
    onResponse({request, response, options}) {
      
      items.value = response._data
      totalItems.value = response.headers.get('x-total-count')
      
    }
  })
})
```

... but this results in 2 API requests and on the initial page load totalItems is `0` and items is `[]` until updating with the correct values a few moments later which feels a bit sluggish.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Having used and loved Nuxt 2 for the last few years I have recently taken the plunge to v3 and it is not an easy ride :(

Comment: The external API you are referring to is from wordpress or no?

Comment: No, it's a bespoke API developed using Ruby on Rails but that should be irrelevant as it is returning the header info and json body in the expected format.  The issue seems to be with Nuxt 3 (or how I am using it).  Thanks.